# Sentiment analysis with Stanford CoreNLP in Python

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am learning NLP and have just installed the Stanford CoreNLP.  I use Windows10 and have installed Python3 with Anaconda3. I also installed pycorenlp - 0.3.

I run CoreNLP using the following command in the directory where the files have been downloaded and extracted.

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

[image]

In my Jupyter Notebook I run the following piece of code I found in the web:

```
import json, requests

class StanfordCoreNLP:

        """
        Modified from https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp (https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp)
        """
        def __init__(self, server_url):
            # TODO: Error handling? More checking on the url?
            if server_url[-1] == '/':
                server_url = server_url[:-1]
            self.server_url = server_url

        def annotate(self, text, properties=None):
            assert isinstance(text, str)

            if properties is None:
                properties = {}
            else:
                assert isinstance(properties, dict)

            # Checks that the Stanford CoreNLP server is started.
            try:
                requests.get(self.server_url)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                raise Exception('Check whether you have started the CoreNLP server e.g.\n'
                                    '$ cd <path_to_core_nlp_folder>/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/ \n'
                    '$ java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port <port>' )

            data = text.encode()
            r = requests.post(
                self.server_url, params={
                        'properties': str(properties)
                }, data=data, headers={'Connection': 'close'})

            output = r.text

            if ('outputFormat' in properties
                and properties['outputFormat'] == 'json'):
                try:
                    output = json.loads(output, encoding='utf-8', strict=True)
                except:
                    pass
            return output

def sentiment_analysis_on_sentence(sentence):
            # The StanfordCoreNLP server is running on http://127.0.0.1:9000 (http://127.0.0.1:9000)
            nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://127.0.0.1:9000 (http://127.0.0.1:9000)')
                    # Json response of all the annotations
            output = nlp.annotate(sentence, properties={
                    "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,parse,sentiment",
                    "outputFormat": "json",
                    # Only split the sentence at End Of Line. We assume that this method only takes in one single sentence.
                    "ssplit.eolonly": "true",
                    # Setting enforceRequirements to skip some annotators and make the process faster
                    "enforceRequirements": "false"
                    })
            # Only care about the result of the first sentence because we assume we only annotate a single sentence 

            return int(output['sentences'][0]['sentimentValue'])
```

However, when I run in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
sentiment_analysis_on_sentence('I like the service.')
```

I get an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LocationParseError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare_url(self, url, params)
    370         try:
--> 371             scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
    372         except LocationParseError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py in parse_url(url)
    198             if not port.isdigit():
--> 199                 raise LocationParseError(url)
    200             try:

LocationParseError: Failed to parse: 127.0.0.1:9000 (http:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidURL                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-e4763a0324a6> in <module>()
----> 1 sentiment_analysis_on_sentence('I like the service.')

<ipython-input-141-9cf27500efe3> in sentiment_analysis_on_sentence(sentence)
     54                     "ssplit.eolonly": "true",
     55                     # Setting enforceRequirements to skip some annotators and make the process faster
---> 56                     "enforceRequirements": "false"
     57                     })
     58             # Only care about the result of the first sentence because we assume we only annotate a single sentence

<ipython-input-141-9cf27500efe3> in annotate(self, text, properties)
     22             # Checks that the Stanford CoreNLP server is started.
     23             try:
---> 24                 requests.get(self.server_url)
     25             except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
     26                 raise Exception('Check whether you have started the CoreNLP server e.g.\n'

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    492             hooks=hooks,
    493         )
--> 494         prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    495 
    496         proxies = proxies or {}

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in prepare_request(self, request)
    435             auth=merge_setting(auth, self.auth),
    436             cookies=merged_cookies,
--> 437             hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
    438         )
    439         return p

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare(self, method, url, headers, files, data, params, auth, cookies, hooks, json)
    303 
    304         self.prepare_method(method)
--> 305         self.prepare_url(url, params)
    306         self.prepare_headers(headers)
    307         self.prepare_cookies(cookies)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in prepare_url(self, url, params)
    371             scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
    372         except LocationParseError as e:
--> 373             raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
    374 
    375         if not scheme:

InvalidURL: Failed to parse: 127.0.0.1:9000 (http:
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In line 48

```py
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://127.0.0.1:9000 (http://127.0.0.1:9000)')
```

you should remove this `(http://127.0.0.1:9000)` after the first URL with its port.

**Additional Steps:**

As you can see in the command line log, the Stanford NLP uses the lexparser instead of the ShiftReduce Parser.
This is good, since sentiment analysis and the Shiftreduce parser currently have probelms to work together.
To ensure, that both are working you should add

```py
    "parse.model": "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"
```

to the calling properties (see line 50 f.).

For Users in germany:
You might get still an error at the end, if the Stanford CoreNLP Server is started with the wrong locale and you receive an invalid JSON-File.
Then you should add the following [paramters](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/246#issuecomment-516489725) to your server start:

```sh
"-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US Default"
```